# Vuetify text field in data table item slot

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm cloning an array and using `map` to add a property to each object in the array. For some reason when I do this the added property is not being updated when used in `v-model`. Any ideas why this is happening?

In the below code typing in the text field does not update the item quantity. How can the code be altered so that it does?

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="items"
  >
    <template v-slot:item.quantity="props">
      <v-text-field v-model="props.item.quantity"></v-text-field>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    customer: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    headers: [
      { text: 'ID', value: 'id' },
      { text: 'Description', value: 'description' },
      { text: 'Quantity', value: 'quantity' },
    ],
    items: []
  }),
  created() {
    this.initialize()
  },
  methods: {
    initialize() {
      const items = [...this.customer.items]
      items.map(item => {
        item.quantity = ''
      })
      this.items = items
    }
}
</script>
```

Customer is a JSON response from API

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Customer",
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "product": 1707,
      "contract": null,
      "plu": "709000",
      "description": "ABC",
      "unit": 1,
      "price": "5.20"
    }
  ],
}
```

**Update**

[Link to codepen](https://codepen.io/bdoubleu/pen/bGGWXjO) - typing in the `qty2` field does not update the data because it was added to the object with `map`.

Comment: Try with `v-slot:item.quantity="{ item }"` `v-model="item.quantity"`.

Comment: Can you please share the sample object of this.customer.items, in question, that would really help to solve your issue

Comment: @azeós that doesn't work either

Comment: @chans question updated

Comment: The above approach will update the object , when you change the value in text box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that you need to do a deep copy of the `customer.items` before using `map` to add the new object property.

```
initialize() {
  let items = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.customer.items))
  items.map(item => {
    item.quantity = '5'
    return item
  })
  this.items = items
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The above code is working as expected, I've reproduced the same scenario in codepen

find the working code here: https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/gOOWJGJ?editors=1010

Try make changes to the first text box in the data-table for testing purpose and check the console it updates the items object on typing

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      :items-per-page="5"
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template v-slot:item.protein="props">
        <v-text-field
          v-model="props.item.protein"
          name="quantity"
          outlined
          @input="getdata"
          type="number"
        ></v-text-field>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '8%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          iron: '16%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          iron: '0%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          iron: '2%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          iron: '45%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          iron: '22%',
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          iron: '6%',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getdata() {
      console.log(this.desserts[0].protein);
    }
  },
})
```

Comment: Let me know, if this works fine as per your requirement

Comment: The problem is in the map. If I add a property to the object using map then it can't be updated

Comment: I've just solved using a deep copy - thanks for your help